# MS Access List Box Lookup on Table Not Showing in SubForm

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2010

I have a list box lookup embedded into one of my tables:

[image]

This works fine and shows up in the datasheet view of the table.

[image]

However, I built a form, bound to the table, but the drop down list does not show up in the datasheet view (or the form view) of the form.

[image]

I am at a loss as to why. The form itself allows additions / deletions and edits.

Any insight to get this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What type of control is on the form?  It looks like it is a text box.  Change it to a combobox on the form and see what happens.  You may need to add those values into the combobox on the form.

Comment: thanks @wbeard52 Great idea. I will try on Monday when I am back to work and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that the datasheet view of a form is a separate view on the data, and you can use different controls to view the same data without affecting the table design.

The way to change how fields in datasheet view are displayed in a form is counterintuitive: you need to put the form in design view. You'll then get a presentation of the fields in your form as if you'd created a non-datasheet form. In this view, find the field you want displayed as a combo box, and delete it.

Then, from the toolbox of different controls (Textbox, Label, Button, etc.), click the "Combo Box" button and draw a new combo box. The combo box wizard appears; now you can link your combo box to the field you wanted from your original table, and tell it to display using the same format you specified in your table design -- in this example, you'd choose "let me type in a list of values" and then enter `"Paid"; "Never Paid"; ... etc.` in the little edit table it gives you.

Then save the form and put it back into datasheet view -- you should see a combo box for that field.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new list box using the wizard. The bound property needs to be the control that you want to use for your lookup. If the list box has an sql statement, try changing it to the tables filed name.. I have run into this issue before when using a list box. It is fixable. Access wants to create and sql statement, especially for a find a record type of list box.